# Submit updated ng-model via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I want to submit text stored in a ng-model via JavaScript. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">Enter text here:
            <input type="text" ng-model="in" name="text" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> <pre>Last input: {{active}}</pre>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>    
function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.active = "none";
    $scope.in = "enter input here";
    $scope.submit = function () {

    $http.post("do_something.php",{sometext:$scope.in})
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.active = response.data;
        });
    };
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to write an extension, that enters text into the input field and submits it.

I use JavaScript to access the elements which have the ng-model, and change their value:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value="hello";
```

this only changes the text in my input field, but does not affect the actual in-variable. when submitting the form via

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].click()
```

The submitted input is not the input it previously changed to, but instead the old input - not visible any more.

I think this is because changing values via Javascript does not change the ng-model according to the input fields value.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You're setting the input value as "enter input here"  are you wanting to use that as a placeholder initially?

Comment: Do you use $scope.$apply after you set the value?

Comment: You should put this in a directive. [this](https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/) article shows you the Agular way without the use of $apply

Comment: @Rob Yes, it's probably bad form, this was just an example for me to work with and i could not bother to fill the field by hand.    

sebenalern No, i'll give it a try tomorrow, thanks!    

ste2425 I'll read it tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not very good idea to modify Angular models from outside of the Angular app itself. But given that you have a good reason for that you can do it like this:

```
var input = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]);
var model = input.controller('ngModel');

model.$setViewValue('New value');
model.$render();

input.parent('form').triggerHandler('submit');
```

By working with ngModelController directly you have a benefit that you don't have to know the actual model name. You just use ngModelController API. Another benefit is that you don't need to do error prone stuff like `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].click()`. Instead, just directly trigger function used by `ngSubmit` directive.

Here is a quick demo:

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.in = "enter input here";
  $scope.submit = function() {
    alert('Value submitted: ' + $scope.in);
  };
}

function updateModel() {
  
  var input = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]);
  var model = input.controller('ngModel');

  model.$setViewValue('New value');
  model.$render();

  input.parent('form').triggerHandler('submit');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    Enter text here:
    <input type="text" ng-model="in" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>

<hr>

<p>Set model from outside of the Angular app.</p>
<button onclick="updateModel()">Set model</button>
```

Comment: This works perfect in the developer console, and does even solve a view additional problems I had. Can I use this in an extension too?

Comment: There should be no problems with this thing in extension.

Answer (score 2):

You are going out from the angular environment... That should be avoided, but, sometimes it's needed: in that case you need to manually trigger the `$digest` cycle, this is an example:

```js
function onNoNgClick() {
  var $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('TestForm')).scope();
  
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.value = 'FOOBAZ';
    
    return $scope.submitRequest();
  });
}

function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'Initial Value';
  
  $scope.submitRequest = function() {
    console.log('sendData', $scope.value);
  };
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
return document.getElementById('NoNG').addEventListener('click', onNoNgClick);
});
```

```css
.no-ng {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app='test'>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="submitRequest()" name="testRequest" id="TestForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" />
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="no-ng"><button id="NoNG">SetText: FOOBAZ</button></div>
```